# About the orthogonal vector of an eigenvector, given a matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n \ge 2$, $u \in \mathbb {R}^n$ considered as a column vector with $||u|| = 1$, and $H$ the matrix $$H := I_n - 2uu^T$$ Define $S_{u}^ \bot := \{v \in \mathbb {R}^n : v \cdot u = 0 \}$

.

So far, I've proven that $u$ is an eigenvector of H, the next part of the exercise asks me to prove that any non-zero vector in $S_{u}^ \bot$ is an eigenvector of H. My approach is to assume $v = \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{pmatrix}$ and prove that $Hv = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda$, is this a good approach? Or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v \in S_{u}^{ \bot }$ and then we have by the definition of $H$ $$ Hv= (I_{n}-2u  u^{T})v = I_{n} v - 2u u^{T} v= v-2u(v^{T}u)^{T} =v-2u(v \cdot u)^{T} = v $$
So all the non-zero vectors in $S_{u}^{ \bot}$ are eigenvectors of $H$.

Comment: Great explanation! I'm pretty new to linear algebra, yet this makes me understand the exercise more clearly!

Comment: Glad to hear that.